# How can I convert a number in a cell to time format when sending this cell via email?

Tags: excel, vba

I send emails via my Outlook using VBA. My mail macro contains placeholder that work fine. For example I can use `[Date]` in my message and it gets replaced with the date in cell B2.

I also have a cell that contains a time in this format: `HH:MM` (`07:00` or `20:30` etc.)
But the problem is when I send the email via Outlook I don't see `07:00` but instead it is replaced by `0,291666666666667`

```vb
Abs1 = Replace(Abs1, "[Von]", Sheets("Reservierung").Cells(2, "C").Value)
```

This line replaces the placeholder with the Value in the Cell.
Now I need something to convert this number via code to this format: `HH:MM`

How does this work?

Comment: Use `Format(Range("whichever range you have").Value, "hh:mm")`

Comment: If the cell is *displaying* the date, then you should be able to use `Cells(2, "C").Text`. Alternatively, you can force the formatting to any style you wish using `Format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Value` instead of `Text`:

```
Abs1 = Replace(Abs1, "[Von]", Sheets("Reservierung").Cells(2, "C").Value)
```

Try the following:

```
Abs1 = Replace(Abs1, "[Von]", Sheets("Reservierung").Cells(2, "C").Text)
```

and make sure to apply "Time" format to the cell (using Ctrl-1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Format` function to [convert a string to a date or time value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) like so:

```
Format(Range("whichever range you have").Value, "hh:mm")
```

In your code this would be:

```
Abs1 = Replace(Abs1, "[Von]", Format(Sheets("Reservierung").Cells(2, "C").Value,"hh:mm"))
```